# TextField, button changing position after viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, constraints

When I initially load my screen, there is a textview and button that are in the incorrect Y position. After less than a second, they move down to the correct position. You can see what's going on here in these two pictures. Any one know why this is happening? It happens in one other screen as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your constraint.. it's leading space maybe had over superview

Comment: It looks like that the sub view added programmatically, in the picture 1, the keyboard also misalign, maybe you can try to disable the TextView first, see what happen.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code of some sorts.